# How does the number of CPUs affect Python code?

Tags: python

I have two EC2 instance: one instance has 16 CPUs and 64 GiB memory; while the other one has 1 CPUs and 1 GiB RAM. When I ran this code it seems they have the same result, why?

```
import time

t1 = int(time.time())
x = 0

while x < 1000000:
    x = x + 1
    print(x)

t2 = int(time.time())
print(t1-t2)
```

The first instance gives me 54 seconds while the second gives me 46 seconds. How can I use all of the resources available? Does CPU and RAM matter over Python?

Comment: If you want to saturate more than one CPU core, you need to use multiple processes (eg multiprocess library).

Comment: To add to @jordanms answer try running 16 instances of your code on at the same time on each machine. Then you might see a time difference.